# Why can I set any event type string to invoke addEventListener & without setTimeout I lose my css effect?

Tags: javascript, css, lazy-loading, addeventlistener

I'm learning JavaScript from javascript30.
Now in the chapter 13, I try to change and add more function in this test.

So I builde this page for try lazyload with css effect,
when scroll to image 1/2 height, set src from `<ima data-imglink>` and add class to set css effect.

But there have some weird thing I don't know why:

1. why `addEventListener` can set anything in first argument to invoke `imgActive` ?
2. why if i remove `setTimeout`, that just show image without css effect.

You can see the javascript code below,
if you know what happen about that, please tell me why, Thanks :) !

**edit**:
Add CodePen link here -> https://codepen.io/Gua/pen/BdKrgv

**edit**:
Thank Fred, I know what happened now,
Can't set function with argument in `addEventListener` like this:

```
sliderImage.addEventListener('load', imgActive(sliderImage));
```

It will make listener fail and call the function immediately;
that's why I can set anything in first argument and can invoke `imgActive`.

So if want to call some function with argument, the good way is always use anonymous function to do, like this:

```
sliderImage.addEventListener('load', () => {
  imgActive(sliderImage);
})
```

Thank Fred again, I got answer, cheers!

**original snippet**:

```js
const sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-in');

function checkSlide() {  
  sliderImages.forEach(sliderImage => {
    const slideInAt = (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight) - (sliderImage.height / 2);
    const imageBottom = sliderImage.offsetTop + sliderImage.height;
    const isHalfShown = slideInAt > sliderImage.offsetTop;
    const isNotScrolledPast = window.scrollY < imageBottom;
    const isActive = sliderImage.classList.contains('active');
    
    if (isHalfShown && isNotScrolledPast && !isActive) {
      const imageLink = sliderImage.dataset.imglink;
      sliderImage.setAttribute('src', imageLink);
      //↓set anything in first argument still can invoke imgActive
      sliderImage.addEventListener('whyyyy ican invoke imgActive??', imgActive(sliderImage));
      //↓ this is what i want to do, when image loaded to invoke imgActive.
      //sliderImage.addEventListener('load', imgActive(sliderImage));
    }
  })
}

function imgActive(sliderImage) {
  //↓ if remove setTimeout, just show image without css effect.
  //  even i just set 1ms for setTimeout function.
  setTimeout(function() {
     sliderImage.classList.add('active');
  }, 1);
  //↓ this is what i want to do, just add class "active".
  //sliderImage.classList.add('active');
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', checkSlide)
```

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'helvetica neue';
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 200;
  }
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  *,
  *:before,
  *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }
  h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .site-wrap {
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    background: white;
    padding: 40px;
    text-align: justify;
  }
  .align-left {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .align-right {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  .slide-in {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s;
    height:200px;
  }
  .align-left.slide-in {
    transform: translateX(-30%) scale(0.95);
  }
  .align-right.slide-in {
    transform: translateX(30%) scale(0.95);
  }
  .slide-in.active {
    opacity: 1;
    height: unset;
    transform: translateX(0%) scale(1);
  }
```

```html
<div class="site-wrap">

  <h1>Slide in on Scroll</h1>
  <p>Consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore tempora rerum, est autem cupiditate, corporis a qui libero ipsum delectus quidem dolor at nulla, adipisci veniam in reiciendis aut asperiores omnis blanditiis quod quas laborum nam! Fuga ad tempora in aspernatur
    pariaturlores sunt esse magni, ut, dignissimos.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum cupiditate, corporis a qui libero ipsum delectus quidem dolor at nulla, adipisci veniam in reiciendis aut asperiores omnis blanditiis quod quas laborum nam! Fuga ad tempora in aspernatur pariatur fugit quibusdam dolores sunt esse magni,
    ut, dignissimos.</p>
  <p>Adipisicing elit. Tempore tempora rerum..</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore tempora rerum, est autem cupiditate, corporis a qui libero ipsum delectus quidem dolor at nulla, adipisci veniam in reiciendis aut asperiores omnis blanditiis quod quas laborum nam! Fuga
    ad tempora in aspernatur pariatur fugit quibusdam dolores sunt esse magni, ut, dignissimos.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore tempora rerum, est autem cupiditate, corporis a qui libero ipsum delectus quidem dolor at nulla, adipisci veniam in reiciendis aut asperiores omnis blanditiis quod quas laborum nam! Fuga
    ad tempora in aspernatur pariatur fugit quibusdam dolores sunt esse magni, ut, dignissimos.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore tempora rerum, est autem cupiditate, corporis a qui libero ipsum delectus quidem dolor at nulla, adipisci veniam in reiciendis aut asperiores omnis blanditiis quod quas laborum nam! Fuga
    ad tempora in aspernatur pariatur fugit quibusdam dolores sunt esse magni, ut, dignissimos.</p>

  <img src="" data-imglink="http://unsplash.it/400/400" class="align-left slide-in">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates, deserunt facilis et iste corrupti omnis tenetur est. Iste ut est dicta dolor itaque adipisci, dolorum minima, veritatis earum provident error molestias. Ratione magni illo sint vel
    velit ut excepturi consectetur suscipit, earum modi accusamus voluptatem nostrum, praesentium numquam, reiciendis voluptas sit id quisquam. Consequatur in quis reprehenderit modi perspiciatis necessitatibus saepe, quidem, suscipit iure natus dignissimos
    ipsam, eligendi deleniti accusantium, rerum quibusdam fugit perferendis et optio recusandae sed ratione. Culpa, dolorum reprehenderit harum ab voluptas fuga, nisi eligendi natus maiores illum quas quos et aperiam aut doloremque optio maxime fugiat
    doloribus. Eum dolorum expedita quam, nesciunt</p>

  <img src="" data-imglink="http://unsplash.it/400/401" class="align-right slide-in">

  <p> at provident praesentium atque quas rerum optio dignissimos repudiandae ullam illum quibusdam. Vel ad error quibusdam, illo ex totam placeat. Quos excepturi fuga, molestiae ea quisquam minus, ratione dicta consectetur officia omnis, doloribus voluptatibus?
    Veniam ipsum veritatis architecto, provident quas consequatur doloremque quam quidem earum expedita, ad delectus voluptatum, omnis praesentium nostrum qui aspernatur ea eaque adipisci et cumque ab? Ea voluptatum dolore itaque odio. Eius minima distinctio
    harum, officia ab nihil exercitationem. Tempora rem nemo nam temporibus molestias facilis minus ipsam quam doloribus consequatur debitis nesciunt tempore officiis aperiam quisquam, molestiae voluptates cum, fuga culpa. Distinctio accusamus quibusdam,
    tempore perspiciatis dolorum optio facere consequatur quidem ullam beatae architecto, ipsam sequi officiis dignissimos amet impedit natus necessitatibus tenetur repellendus dolor rem! Dicta dolorem, iure, facilis illo ex nihil ipsa amet officia, optio
    temporibus eum autem odit repellendus nisi. Possimus modi, corrupti error debitis doloribus dicta libero earum, sequi porro ut excepturi nostrum ea voluptatem nihil culpa? Ullam expedita eligendi obcaecati reiciendis velit provident omnis quas qui
    in corrupti est dolore facere ad hic, animi soluta assumenda consequuntur reprehenderit! Voluptate dolor nihil veniam laborum voluptas nisi pariatur sed optio accusantium quam consectetur, corrupti, sequi et consequuntur, excepturi doloremque. Tempore
    quis velit corporis neque fugit non sequi eaque rem hic. Facere, inventore, aspernatur. Accusantium modi atque, asperiores qui nobis soluta cumque suscipit excepturi possimus doloremque odit saepe perferendis temporibus molestiae nostrum voluptatum
    quis id sint quidem nesciunt culpa. Rerum labore dolor beatae blanditiis praesentium explicabo velit optio esse aperiam similique, voluptatem cum, maiores ipsa tempore. Reiciendis sed culpa atque inventore, nam ullam enim expedita consectetur id velit
    iusto alias vitae explicabo nemo neque odio reprehenderit soluta sint eaque. Aperiam, qui ut tenetur, voluptate doloremque officiis dicta quaerat voluptatem rerum natus magni. Eum amet autem dolor ullam.</p>

  <img src="" data-imglink="http://unsplash.it/200/500" class="align-left slide-in">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio maiores adipisci quibusdam repudiandae dolor vero placeat esse sit! Quibusdam saepe aperiam explicabo placeat optio, consequuntur nihil voluptatibus expedita quia vero perferendis,
    deserunt et incidunt eveniet <img src="" data-imglink="http://unsplash.it/200/200" class="align-right slide-in"> temporibus doloremque possimus facilis. Possimus labore, officia dolore! Eaque ratione saepe, alias harum laboriosam deserunt laudantium
    blanditiis eum explicabo placeat reiciendis labore iste sint. Consectetur expedita dignissimos, non quos distinctio, eos rerum facilis eligendi. Asperiores laudantium, rerum ratione consequatur, culpa consectetur possimus atque ab tempore illum non
    dolor nesciunt. Neque, rerum. A vel non incidunt, quod doloremque dignissimos necessitatibus aliquid laboriosam architecto at cupiditate commodi expedita in, quae blanditiis. Deserunt labore sequi, repellat laboriosam est, doloremque culpa reiciendis
    tempore excepturi. Enim nostrum fugit itaque vel corporis ullam sed tenetur ipsa qui rem quam error sint, libero. Laboriosam rem, ratione. Autem blanditiis</p>


  <p>laborum neque repudiandae quam, cumque, voluptate veritatis itaque, placeat veniam ad nisi. Expedita, laborum reprehenderit ratione soluta velit natus, odit mollitia. Corporis rerum minima fugiat in nostrum. Assumenda natus cupiditate hic quidem ex,
    quas, amet ipsum esse dolore facilis beatae maxime qui inventore, iste? Maiores dignissimos dolore culpa debitis voluptatem harum, excepturi enim reiciendis, tempora ab ipsam illum aspernatur quasi qui porro saepe iure sunt eligendi tenetur quaerat
    ducimus quas sequi omnis aperiam suscipit! Molestiae obcaecati officiis quo, ratione eveniet, provident pariatur. Veniam quasi expedita distinctio, itaque molestiae sequi, dolorum nisi repellendus quia facilis iusto dignissimos nam? Tenetur fugit
    quos autem nihil, perspiciatis expedita enim tempore, alias ab maiores quis necessitatibus distinctio molestias eum, quidem. Delectus impedit quidem laborum, fugit vel neque quo, ipsam, quasi aspernatur quas odio nihil? Veniam amet reiciendis blanditiis
    quis reprehenderit repudiandae neque, ab ducimus, odit excepturi voluptate saepe ipsam. Voluptatem eum error voluptas porro officiis, amet! Molestias, fugit, ut! Tempore non magnam, amet, facere ducimus accusantium eos veritatis neque.</p>

  <img src="" data-imglink="http://unsplash.it/400/400" class="align-right slide-in">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio maiores adipisci quibusdam repudiandae dolor vero placeat esse sit! Quibusdam saepe aperiam explicabo placeat optio, consequuntur nihil voluptatibus expedita quia vero perferendis,
    deserunt et incidunt eveniet temporibus doloremque possimus facilis. Possimus labore, officia dolore! Eaque ratione saepe, alias harum laboriosam deserunt laudantium blanditiis eum explicabo placeat reiciendis labore iste sint. Consectetur expedita
    dignissimos, non quos distinctio, eos rerum facilis eligendi. Asperiores laudantium, rerum ratione consequatur, culpa consectetur possimus atque ab tempore illum non dolor nesciunt. Neque, rerum. A vel non incidunt, quod doloremque dignissimos necessitatibus
    aliquid laboriosam architecto at cupiditate commodi expedita in, quae blanditiis. Deserunt labore sequi, repellat laboriosam est, doloremque culpa reiciendis tempore excepturi. Enim nostrum fugit itaque vel corporis ullam sed tenetur ipsa qui rem
    quam error sint, libero. Laboriosam rem, ratione. Autem blanditiis laborum neque repudiandae quam, cumque, voluptate veritatis itaque, placeat veniam ad nisi. Expedita, laborum reprehenderit ratione soluta velit natus, odit mollitia. Corporis rerum
    minima fugiat in nostrum. Assumenda natus cupiditate hic quidem ex, quas, amet ipsum esse dolore facilis beatae maxime qui inventore, iste? Maiores dignissimos dolore culpa debitis voluptatem harum, excepturi enim reiciendis, tempora ab ipsam illum
    aspernatur quasi qui porro saepe iure sunt eligendi tenetur quaerat ducimus quas sequi omnis aperiam suscipit! Molestiae obcaecati officiis quo, ratione eveniet, provident pariatur. Veniam quasi expedita distinctio, itaque molestiae sequi, dolorum
    nisi repellendus quia facilis iusto dignissimos nam? Tenetur fugit quos autem nihil, perspiciatis expedita enim tempore, alias ab maiores quis necessitatibus distinctio molestias eum, quidem. Delectus impedit quidem laborum, fugit vel neque quo, ipsam,
    quasi aspernatur quas odio nihil? Veniam amet reiciendis blanditiis quis reprehenderit repudiandae neque, ab ducimus, odit excepturi voluptate saepe ipsam. Voluptatem eum error voluptas porro officiis, amet! Molestias, fugit, ut! Tempore non magnam,
    amet, facere ducimus accusantium eos veritatis neque.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio maiores adipisci quibusdam repudiandae dolor vero placeat esse sit! Quibusdam saepe aperiam explicabo placeat optio, consequuntur nihil voluptatibus expedita quia vero perferendis,
    deserunt et incidunt eveniet temporibus doloremque possimus facilis. Possimus labore, officia dolore! Eaque ratione saepe, alias harum laboriosam deserunt laudantium blanditiis eum explicabo placeat reiciendis labore iste sint. Consectetur expedita
    dignissimos, non quos distinctio, eos rerum facilis eligendi. Asperiores laudantium, rerum ratione consequatur, culpa consectetur possimus atque ab tempore illum non dolor nesciunt. Neque, rerum. A vel non incidunt, quod doloremque dignissimos necessitatibus
    aliquid laboriosam architecto at cupiditate commodi expedita in, quae blanditiis. Deserunt labore sequi, repellat laboriosam est, doloremque culpa reiciendis tempore excepturi. Enim nostrum fugit itaque vel corporis ullam sed tenetur ipsa qui rem
    quam error sint, libero. Laboriosam rem, ratione. Autem blanditiis laborum neque repudiandae quam, cumque, voluptate veritatis itaque, placeat veniam ad nisi. Expedita, laborum reprehenderit ratione soluta velit natus, odit mollitia. Corporis rerum
    minima fugiat in nostrum. Assumenda natus cupiditate hic quidem ex, quas, amet ipsum esse dolore facilis beatae maxime qui inventore, iste? Maiores dignissimos dolore culpa debitis voluptatem harum, excepturi enim reiciendis, tempora ab ipsam illum
    aspernatur quasi qui porro saepe iure sunt eligendi tenetur quaerat ducimus quas sequi omnis aperiam suscipit! Molestiae obcaecati officiis quo, ratione eveniet, provident pariatur. Veniam quasi expedita distinctio, itaque molestiae sequi, dolorum
    nisi repellendus quia facilis iusto dignissimos nam? Tenetur fugit quos autem nihil, perspiciatis expedita enim tempore, alias ab maiores quis necessitatibus distinctio molestias eum, quidem. Delectus impedit quidem laborum, fugit vel neque quo, ipsam,
    quasi aspernatur quas odio nihil? Veniam amet reiciendis blanditiis quis reprehenderit repudiandae neque, ab ducimus, odit excepturi voluptate saepe ipsam. Voluptatem eum error voluptas porro officiis, amet! Molestias, fugit, ut! Tempore non magnam,
    amet, facere ducimus accusantium eos veritatis neque.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: For .2 it's because at the time `imgActive` is called, no page reflow has been triggered yet, so when you change the class of the element, its CSS properties are not updated (in the sense that they didn't had a previous state). You can force it in code with calling one of `offsetXXX` or `getBoundingClientRect` methods. Also beware of what you're doing in this scroll event, it's a dangerous one (e.g, if your images have no-cache, you might end-up loading a few K times) , and you'd be better removing it as soon as you don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No need for separate function or timeout

I'll be honest with you: I originally had no idea why [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) was apparently working with a random string for its [`type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events), but I assumed it defaulted by some mechanism to a type that actually worked as expected.
The web is complex, and there are many fallbacks in place to keep it from crashing every five seconds.

**However**:

According to [the w3 specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html)

> `addEventListener`
>   ...
>   `type` of type `DOMString`
>   ...
>   No Return Value
>   **No Exceptions**

And since we can [create and trigger custom events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) like:

> `var event = new Event('build');
>   elem.addEventListener('build', function (e) { ... }, false);
>   elem.dispatchEvent(event);`

the interface has to accept any valid [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) we throw at it (with [caveats](https://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-xml-19980210#NT-Name)).

So, if it's offered a `type` it can't do anything with, it simply does nothing.

---

Now; when an event listener is triggered, the connected function can be either:

- A defined function.
- An anonymous function.

A defined function can be either:

Called without parameters, and the `event` will be parsed in automagically:

```
addEventListener( "click", definedFunction, false );
```

Called with parameters, **but then it must be called within an anonymous function**:

```
addEventListener( "click", function( event ) {
  definedFunction( event, some_other_variable );
}, false );
```

**We absolutely cannot do** (note: see end of answer):

```
addEventListener( "click", definedFunction( event, some_other_variable ), false );
```

Try running the following little bit of code in your browser's console, and you'll see that the `"click"` event doesn't work, but whenever you run the line setting the listener on the `body` (try paste>entering it several times), `foo()` will be called, and you'll get the output in the console.

```
function foo( str ) {
  console.log( str );
}
document.body.addEventListener( "click", foo( "bar" ) );
```

So, in your code, whenever `checkSlide()` is called on `"scroll"`, the event listener is not properly set, and no exceptions are thrown, but `imgActive(sliderImage)` is called.

---

Your [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) was needed to get the desired slide in effect because the images were't sliding in on `load`, but rather immediately the listener was not set, so the image hadn't loaded until after the slide in effect had finished; the timeout was acting as a buffer in lieu of waiting for the image to `"load"`.

---

So, here's your code with a couple of small changes, that appears to be working as desired, but with no weird code that makes no sense.

```js
const sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-in');

function checkSlide() {  
  sliderImages.forEach(sliderImage => {
    const slideInAt = (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight) - (sliderImage.height / 2);
    const imageBottom = sliderImage.offsetTop + sliderImage.height;
    const isHalfShown = slideInAt > sliderImage.offsetTop;
    const isNotScrolledPast = window.scrollY < imageBottom;
    const isActive = sliderImage.classList.contains('active');
    if (isHalfShown && isNotScrolledPast && !isActive) {
      const imageLink = sliderImage.dataset.imglink;
      sliderImage.setAttribute('src', imageLink);
      // new code
      sliderImage.addEventListener('load', () => sliderImage.classList.add('active'));
    }
  })
}

// no need for separate function or timeout

window.addEventListener('scroll', checkSlide);
```

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'helvetica neue';
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 200;
  }
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  *,
  *:before,
  *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }
  h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .site-wrap {
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    background: white;
    padding: 40px;
    text-align: justify;
  }
  .align-left {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .align-right {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  .slide-in {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s;
    height:200px;
  }
  .align-left.slide-in {
    transform: translateX(-30%) scale(0.95);
  }
  .align-right.slide-in {
    transform: translateX(30%) scale(0.95);
  }
  .slide-in.active {
    opacity: 1;
    height: unset;
    transform: translateX(0%) scale(1);
  }
```

```html
<div class="site-wrap">

  <h1>Slide in on Scroll</h1>
  <p>Consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore tempora rerum, est autem cupiditate, corporis a qui libero ipsum delectus quidem dolor at nulla, adipisci veniam in reiciendis aut asperiores omnis blanditiis quod quas laborum nam! Fuga ad tempora in aspernatur
    pariaturlores sunt esse magni, ut, dignissimos.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum cupiditate, corporis a qui libero ipsum delectus quidem dolor at nulla, adipisci veniam in reiciendis aut asperiores omnis blanditiis quod quas laborum nam! Fuga ad tempora in aspernatur pariatur fugit quibusdam dolores sunt esse magni,
    ut, dignissimos.</p>
  <p>Adipisicing elit. Tempore tempora rerum..</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore tempora rerum, est autem cupiditate, corporis a qui libero ipsum delectus quidem dolor at nulla, adipisci veniam in reiciendis aut asperiores omnis blanditiis quod quas laborum nam! Fuga
    ad tempora in aspernatur pariatur fugit quibusdam dolores sunt esse magni, ut, dignissimos.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore tempora rerum, est autem cupiditate, corporis a qui libero ipsum delectus quidem dolor at nulla, adipisci veniam in reiciendis aut asperiores omnis blanditiis quod quas laborum nam! Fuga
    ad tempora in aspernatur pariatur fugit quibusdam dolores sunt esse magni, ut, dignissimos.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore tempora rerum, est autem cupiditate, corporis a qui libero ipsum delectus quidem dolor at nulla, adipisci veniam in reiciendis aut asperiores omnis blanditiis quod quas laborum nam! Fuga
    ad tempora in aspernatur pariatur fugit quibusdam dolores sunt esse magni, ut, dignissimos.</p>

  <img src="" data-imglink="http://unsplash.it/400/400" class="align-left slide-in">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates, deserunt facilis et iste corrupti omnis tenetur est. Iste ut est dicta dolor itaque adipisci, dolorum minima, veritatis earum provident error molestias. Ratione magni illo sint vel
    velit ut excepturi consectetur suscipit, earum modi accusamus voluptatem nostrum, praesentium numquam, reiciendis voluptas sit id quisquam. Consequatur in quis reprehenderit modi perspiciatis necessitatibus saepe, quidem, suscipit iure natus dignissimos
    ipsam, eligendi deleniti accusantium, rerum quibusdam fugit perferendis et optio recusandae sed ratione. Culpa, dolorum reprehenderit harum ab voluptas fuga, nisi eligendi natus maiores illum quas quos et aperiam aut doloremque optio maxime fugiat
    doloribus. Eum dolorum expedita quam, nesciunt</p>

  <img src="" data-imglink="http://unsplash.it/400/401" class="align-right slide-in">

  <p> at provident praesentium atque quas rerum optio dignissimos repudiandae ullam illum quibusdam. Vel ad error quibusdam, illo ex totam placeat. Quos excepturi fuga, molestiae ea quisquam minus, ratione dicta consectetur officia omnis, doloribus voluptatibus?
    Veniam ipsum veritatis architecto, provident quas consequatur doloremque quam quidem earum expedita, ad delectus voluptatum, omnis praesentium nostrum qui aspernatur ea eaque adipisci et cumque ab? Ea voluptatum dolore itaque odio. Eius minima distinctio
    harum, officia ab nihil exercitationem. Tempora rem nemo nam temporibus molestias facilis minus ipsam quam doloribus consequatur debitis nesciunt tempore officiis aperiam quisquam, molestiae voluptates cum, fuga culpa. Distinctio accusamus quibusdam,
    tempore perspiciatis dolorum optio facere consequatur quidem ullam beatae architecto, ipsam sequi officiis dignissimos amet impedit natus necessitatibus tenetur repellendus dolor rem! Dicta dolorem, iure, facilis illo ex nihil ipsa amet officia, optio
    temporibus eum autem odit repellendus nisi. Possimus modi, corrupti error debitis doloribus dicta libero earum, sequi porro ut excepturi nostrum ea voluptatem nihil culpa? Ullam expedita eligendi obcaecati reiciendis velit provident omnis quas qui
    in corrupti est dolore facere ad hic, animi soluta assumenda consequuntur reprehenderit! Voluptate dolor nihil veniam laborum voluptas nisi pariatur sed optio accusantium quam consectetur, corrupti, sequi et consequuntur, excepturi doloremque. Tempore
    quis velit corporis neque fugit non sequi eaque rem hic. Facere, inventore, aspernatur. Accusantium modi atque, asperiores qui nobis soluta cumque suscipit excepturi possimus doloremque odit saepe perferendis temporibus molestiae nostrum voluptatum
    quis id sint quidem nesciunt culpa. Rerum labore dolor beatae blanditiis praesentium explicabo velit optio esse aperiam similique, voluptatem cum, maiores ipsa tempore. Reiciendis sed culpa atque inventore, nam ullam enim expedita consectetur id velit
    iusto alias vitae explicabo nemo neque odio reprehenderit soluta sint eaque. Aperiam, qui ut tenetur, voluptate doloremque officiis dicta quaerat voluptatem rerum natus magni. Eum amet autem dolor ullam.</p>

  <img src="" data-imglink="http://unsplash.it/200/500" class="align-left slide-in">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio maiores adipisci quibusdam repudiandae dolor vero placeat esse sit! Quibusdam saepe aperiam explicabo placeat optio, consequuntur nihil voluptatibus expedita quia vero perferendis,
    deserunt et incidunt eveniet <img src="" data-imglink="http://unsplash.it/200/200" class="align-right slide-in"> temporibus doloremque possimus facilis. Possimus labore, officia dolore! Eaque ratione saepe, alias harum laboriosam deserunt laudantium
    blanditiis eum explicabo placeat reiciendis labore iste sint. Consectetur expedita dignissimos, non quos distinctio, eos rerum facilis eligendi. Asperiores laudantium, rerum ratione consequatur, culpa consectetur possimus atque ab tempore illum non
    dolor nesciunt. Neque, rerum. A vel non incidunt, quod doloremque dignissimos necessitatibus aliquid laboriosam architecto at cupiditate commodi expedita in, quae blanditiis. Deserunt labore sequi, repellat laboriosam est, doloremque culpa reiciendis
    tempore excepturi. Enim nostrum fugit itaque vel corporis ullam sed tenetur ipsa qui rem quam error sint, libero. Laboriosam rem, ratione. Autem blanditiis</p>


  <p>laborum neque repudiandae quam, cumque, voluptate veritatis itaque, placeat veniam ad nisi. Expedita, laborum reprehenderit ratione soluta velit natus, odit mollitia. Corporis rerum minima fugiat in nostrum. Assumenda natus cupiditate hic quidem ex,
    quas, amet ipsum esse dolore facilis beatae maxime qui inventore, iste? Maiores dignissimos dolore culpa debitis voluptatem harum, excepturi enim reiciendis, tempora ab ipsam illum aspernatur quasi qui porro saepe iure sunt eligendi tenetur quaerat
    ducimus quas sequi omnis aperiam suscipit! Molestiae obcaecati officiis quo, ratione eveniet, provident pariatur. Veniam quasi expedita distinctio, itaque molestiae sequi, dolorum nisi repellendus quia facilis iusto dignissimos nam? Tenetur fugit
    quos autem nihil, perspiciatis expedita enim tempore, alias ab maiores quis necessitatibus distinctio molestias eum, quidem. Delectus impedit quidem laborum, fugit vel neque quo, ipsam, quasi aspernatur quas odio nihil? Veniam amet reiciendis blanditiis
    quis reprehenderit repudiandae neque, ab ducimus, odit excepturi voluptate saepe ipsam. Voluptatem eum error voluptas porro officiis, amet! Molestias, fugit, ut! Tempore non magnam, amet, facere ducimus accusantium eos veritatis neque.</p>

  <img src="" data-imglink="http://unsplash.it/400/400" class="align-right slide-in">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio maiores adipisci quibusdam repudiandae dolor vero placeat esse sit! Quibusdam saepe aperiam explicabo placeat optio, consequuntur nihil voluptatibus expedita quia vero perferendis,
    deserunt et incidunt eveniet temporibus doloremque possimus facilis. Possimus labore, officia dolore! Eaque ratione saepe, alias harum laboriosam deserunt laudantium blanditiis eum explicabo placeat reiciendis labore iste sint. Consectetur expedita
    dignissimos, non quos distinctio, eos rerum facilis eligendi. Asperiores laudantium, rerum ratione consequatur, culpa consectetur possimus atque ab tempore illum non dolor nesciunt. Neque, rerum. A vel non incidunt, quod doloremque dignissimos necessitatibus
    aliquid laboriosam architecto at cupiditate commodi expedita in, quae blanditiis. Deserunt labore sequi, repellat laboriosam est, doloremque culpa reiciendis tempore excepturi. Enim nostrum fugit itaque vel corporis ullam sed tenetur ipsa qui rem
    quam error sint, libero. Laboriosam rem, ratione. Autem blanditiis laborum neque repudiandae quam, cumque, voluptate veritatis itaque, placeat veniam ad nisi. Expedita, laborum reprehenderit ratione soluta velit natus, odit mollitia. Corporis rerum
    minima fugiat in nostrum. Assumenda natus cupiditate hic quidem ex, quas, amet ipsum esse dolore facilis beatae maxime qui inventore, iste? Maiores dignissimos dolore culpa debitis voluptatem harum, excepturi enim reiciendis, tempora ab ipsam illum
    aspernatur quasi qui porro saepe iure sunt eligendi tenetur quaerat ducimus quas sequi omnis aperiam suscipit! Molestiae obcaecati officiis quo, ratione eveniet, provident pariatur. Veniam quasi expedita distinctio, itaque molestiae sequi, dolorum
    nisi repellendus quia facilis iusto dignissimos nam? Tenetur fugit quos autem nihil, perspiciatis expedita enim tempore, alias ab maiores quis necessitatibus distinctio molestias eum, quidem. Delectus impedit quidem laborum, fugit vel neque quo, ipsam,
    quasi aspernatur quas odio nihil? Veniam amet reiciendis blanditiis quis reprehenderit repudiandae neque, ab ducimus, odit excepturi voluptate saepe ipsam. Voluptatem eum error voluptas porro officiis, amet! Molestias, fugit, ut! Tempore non magnam,
    amet, facere ducimus accusantium eos veritatis neque.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio maiores adipisci quibusdam repudiandae dolor vero placeat esse sit! Quibusdam saepe aperiam explicabo placeat optio, consequuntur nihil voluptatibus expedita quia vero perferendis,
    deserunt et incidunt eveniet temporibus doloremque possimus facilis. Possimus labore, officia dolore! Eaque ratione saepe, alias harum laboriosam deserunt laudantium blanditiis eum explicabo placeat reiciendis labore iste sint. Consectetur expedita
    dignissimos, non quos distinctio, eos rerum facilis eligendi. Asperiores laudantium, rerum ratione consequatur, culpa consectetur possimus atque ab tempore illum non dolor nesciunt. Neque, rerum. A vel non incidunt, quod doloremque dignissimos necessitatibus
    aliquid laboriosam architecto at cupiditate commodi expedita in, quae blanditiis. Deserunt labore sequi, repellat laboriosam est, doloremque culpa reiciendis tempore excepturi. Enim nostrum fugit itaque vel corporis ullam sed tenetur ipsa qui rem
    quam error sint, libero. Laboriosam rem, ratione. Autem blanditiis laborum neque repudiandae quam, cumque, voluptate veritatis itaque, placeat veniam ad nisi. Expedita, laborum reprehenderit ratione soluta velit natus, odit mollitia. Corporis rerum
    minima fugiat in nostrum. Assumenda natus cupiditate hic quidem ex, quas, amet ipsum esse dolore facilis beatae maxime qui inventore, iste? Maiores dignissimos dolore culpa debitis voluptatem harum, excepturi enim reiciendis, tempora ab ipsam illum
    aspernatur quasi qui porro saepe iure sunt eligendi tenetur quaerat ducimus quas sequi omnis aperiam suscipit! Molestiae obcaecati officiis quo, ratione eveniet, provident pariatur. Veniam quasi expedita distinctio, itaque molestiae sequi, dolorum
    nisi repellendus quia facilis iusto dignissimos nam? Tenetur fugit quos autem nihil, perspiciatis expedita enim tempore, alias ab maiores quis necessitatibus distinctio molestias eum, quidem. Delectus impedit quidem laborum, fugit vel neque quo, ipsam,
    quasi aspernatur quas odio nihil? Veniam amet reiciendis blanditiis quis reprehenderit repudiandae neque, ab ducimus, odit excepturi voluptate saepe ipsam. Voluptatem eum error voluptas porro officiis, amet! Molestias, fugit, ut! Tempore non magnam,
    amet, facere ducimus accusantium eos veritatis neque.</p>
</div>
```

### For general interest

I took the liberty of altering your JavaScript code significantly to introduce some optimizations:

- `load` listeners are applied to all `.slide-in` images on initialization.
- `load` listeners are now removed immediately after use.
- `scroll` now only checks if the `nextImage` is ready to slide in.
- Simplified maths since until an image loads, it has no `height`, so the only available `height` to calculate from is that set in the CSS. Since that's a hard coded value, there's no point calculating what half of it is every time `scroll` is triggered.
- Removed a lot of measuring.

```js
document.querySelectorAll( '.slide-in' ).forEach( sliderImage => {
  sliderImage.addEventListener( 'load', function slide() {
    this.classList.add( 'active' );
    this.removeEventListener( 'load', slide );
  } );
} );

window.addEventListener( 'scroll', () => {
  const nextImage = document.querySelector( '.slide-in:not(.active)' );
  if ( nextImage && ( window.scrollY + window.innerHeight - 100 ) > nextImage.offsetTop ) {
      nextImage.src = nextImage.dataset.imglink;
  }
} );
```

**I was also thinking** (whilst walking my dog) about my statement that:

> We absolutely cannot do:
>    
>   `addEventListener( "click", definedFunction( event, some_other_variable ), false );`

Well, actually we can, and sometimes it might be quite useful.
The following demonstrates how we can use this feature to alter our listener's function conditionally.
Yes, it's a slightly silly example, but the principle is worth remembering.

```js
var some_value = "baz",
    who_are_you,
    youre_happy,
    you_know_it;

function foo( fnc ) {
  document.body.removeEventListener( "click", who_are_you );
  return {
    bar: function() {
      console.log( "Divide by zero; it's fun!" );
      some_value = undefined;
      doStuff();
    },
    baz: function() {
      console.log( "Always include every library you've ever heard of." );
      document.body.removeEventListener( "click", who_are_you );
    }
  }[ fnc ] || function() {
    console.log( "Phew! It's a good job we had a fallback." );
    some_value = "baz";
    doStuff();
  };
}

function doStuff() {
  if ( youre_happy && you_know_it ) {
    document.body.addEventListener( "click", who_are_you = foo( some_value ) );
  } else {
    some_value = "bar";
    youre_happy = you_know_it = true;
    doStuff();
  }
}

doStuff();
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you Fred, i got same answer from my friend, why i need `setTImeout` because i use `sliderImage.addEventListener('load', imgActive(sliderImage))` with `function imgActive(sliderImage) {
  sliderImage.classList.add('active'); }` brfore, but i fail T_T, i don't know why, so i just add `setTimeout` to test, and it's work ! it's so weird  .

Comment: There's something to explain there; I'll update the answer with details. I am also researching why `addEventListener()` was apparently misbehaving and have some info. Edit to follow.

Comment: @GuaHsu - sorry it took a while, but I have updated the answer with details. I figured out what was going on.

Comment: yeah !! Fred, in the same time i update my qutison too, thank you very mush, i reading it !

Comment: No problem :-) It was quite strange and fun to debug. We both learned something!